# Acces to hostname postgres docker with my local machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose.yml and local.yml file with my project symfony 4. The build docker is success in and a see in a kitmatic a fixtures and migrations is done.

i use cmd:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f local.yml up --build -d
```

In my local.yml i have :

```
  postgres:
    restart: always
    container_name: inlinesd_local_postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ISD
      POSTGRES_USER: ISD2019
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Zr264RTxgHjt45
```

and in my docker-compose:

```
  postgres:
    image: fintrace/postgres-uuid
```

if i have this config in .env local

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://identifiant:mot_passe@postgres:5432/database_name
```

i have a error:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

but if i have a

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://identifiant:mot_passe@0.0.0.0:5432/database_name
```

the fixtures is executed.

I know is a error of hostname but i don't know how to give a hostname postgres docker in my local machin.

if someone can help me please.
Thanks

Comment: Is your project also running in a container or only the database? It is not clear from your post. It would be useful to post the full docker-compose.yml and local.yml. TIP: Have you considered using docker-compose.override.yml instead of local.yml?

Comment: For simplicity, i need to acces a docker hostname "postgres" without change my hosts in my local machin.

if i edit a /etc/hosts  local machin, i had a 127.0.0.1  postrges i have acces of my docker database in my local machin.
But if i don't had this in my hosts local machin i can't acces a docker database in my local machin.
sorry for my english hi

Comment: Adding postgres to /etc/hosts is the way to solve the issue. I also think it's the only way to fix the issue.

Comment: I wonder, for what reason, you had to use `postgres` to visit your database? You set `5432:5432`, this self already has the meaning like: `Hi visitors, please access my service from host's 5432`.